# Envy m6 Laptop unable to left click after typing

Tags: touchpad, typing, mouse-click

I have a problem with my touchpad that whenever I try to click while i have a key pressed it is unresponsive for at least a second until the key is released. Palmcheck is off as I am able to move the pointer with it but I am unable to click anywhere. This comes extremely annoying when I'm playing a game with my laptop that requires to point click and move or anything to requires a combination of using keyboard and clicking simultaneously. Has anybody come accross to this issue? I'm only finding people whose touchpad gets locked and palmcheck solves their problem, but as or me it's the clicking what's locked.

If I have clicked before I start to typed it recognizes that I'm holding the  left click down until I release it but then it locks again until I release the key and 1 second goes by.

Funny enough only the left click is what locks out. I can right click and move the cursor and type at the same time.

I hope somebody can help me out.

I have a Envy m6 HP Laptop with Synaptics touchpad driver.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue, instead of worrying about the driver set up and such, press go to search with windows+W and look for mouse and touch pad settings. This should bring up a tab that will let you modify the delay after clicks.

Oddly enough it will only modify your main click but not the secondary click.